# Why does removing, then re-adding bars to my stack bar chart change the position of the bars?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

In my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k98mm/) if you click the `Pending` button in the legend it should remove the bars that are associated with that category.  This works but when I click the `Reset Legend` button (which provides the `currateData` method with the original data, so that the `Pending` bars come back) it loads the old Pending data out of place.

I believe it has something to do with this method:

```
function redrawPlot() {
    svg = d3.select('svg.chart')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

    svg.selectAll('g.xaxis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + (height - margin.top - margin.bottom) + ')');
}
```

I cannot remove this method because my code is more complex then what is show in the jsfiddle, this is just showing the problem.  I also need to update the width and height in the redraw  method, so I can't just remove it.

How can I change the redrawPlot() method so that when I repopulate my chart it doesn't mess up the bar positions when I add in the old data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the `redrawPlot` function:

```js
var svg;

function initPlot() {
    svg = d3.select('#graphTest') // <-- `svg` is the appended `g`
        .append('svg')
        // ...
        .append('g')

    // ...
}

// ...

function redrawPlot() {
    svg = d3.select('svg.chart') // <-- redefining `svg` to be `svg`

    // ...
}
```

The problem was that you are using global variable `svg` and redefining it in `redrawPlot`. If you preserve the definition of `svg` to be the original definition, the graph updates as required. Making the second definition of `svg` local to `redrawPlot` by adding a `var` solved the problem.

As a sidenote, try to stick to the [reusable chart pattern](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) and avoid using global variables.

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/k98mm/2/)

**If you want to redefine the `svg` variable**

**Disclaimer/Warning**: That is going to lead to unmaintainable code, not recommended.

[<kbd>Demo 2</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/k98mm/3/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  Unfortunately I need to redefine the svg variable there because I'm dealing with changing multiple instances of the plot.  Is there anyway I can redefine the variable, change the height/width, and still get all my bars in the proper position?

Comment: So using what you said I set svg = d3.select('g') and everything work... Thanks for your input!